Today I am not able to compile my application. This is the error that I obtain if I try to Rebuild my project
first, I was getting this error

Then after updating the plugin awesome notifications, I was getting this error:


ERROR:C:\Users\Manish.gradle\caches\transforms-3\7ebc0b898577552074911e60952d6748\transformed\jetified-appcompat-resources-1.7.0-runtime.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerExceptionERROR:C:\Users\Manish.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a9b60d8be52f73d439c133cca1 e82278\transformed\appcompat-1.7.0-runtime.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException.


ERROR:C:\Users\Manish.gradle\caches\transforms-3\7ebc0b898577552074911e60952d6748\transformed\jetified-appcompat-resources-1.7.0-runtime.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerExceptionERROR:C:\Users\Manish.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a9b60d8be52f73d439c133cca1e82278\transformed\appcompat-1.7.0-runtime.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Today I started building my app, just I ran the project but it was giving me the error for a plugin awesome notifications, then I updated the plugin with version 0.10.0. then build again the project, but giving this error, I am able to build apk but not able to run and debug the project.

You might need to check that your Gradle version is compatible with the awesome_notification plugin.
